# How to implement a select() functionality in a charecter driver

Tags: c, linux, driver, polling

I am trying to make a character driver which need to provide a select() functionality to the application using it. With my knowledge it is implemented with poll(). But I am not able to go do this. Is there any way i can do this?
This is my application program.

```
int main()
{
    int fd;
    fd_set fdset;
    struct pollfd ufds;
    struct timeval time;
    time.tv_sec = 2;
    fd = open("/dev/char_dev" , O_RDWR );

    ufds.fd = fd;
    ufds.events = POLLIN | POLLPRI;

    FD_ZERO( &fdset );
    FD_SET( fd , &fdset );

    //poll(&ufds, 1, 3500);

    select( 1, &fdset,  NULL, NULL,&time );


    return 0;
}
```

This is a part of my kernel module. I just wanted to see this message in the dmesg

```
unsigned int dc_poll( struct file *filp,  poll_table *wait )
{
    printk("*****select\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying in the c language with the character driver implementation and test application also written written using  c